# How to customize preview when context menu is presented in swift

Tags: swift

I have created custom UIViewController and included it in contextMenuInteraction (below example):

```
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: MyPawnPreviewProvider.init) { _ -> UIMenu? in
return self.createContextMenu()
    }
}
```

I don't know what to put inside this class to properly customize it:

```
class MyPawnPreviewProvider: UIViewController {
    private let imageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is when I long tap a knight icon (see screenshot), I want context menu to appear but without blurred background and without rescaling the icon.
[the board of the game with knight icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UtlU.png)

Default behaviour is that the icon is zoomed and background is blurred. I want the board to be visible all the time (apart from the context menu area of course).
[after tap and hold the knight icon presenting context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zFil.png)

Comment: I managed to set proper size of preview. But still I don't know how to eliminate blurred background.